# Aurelia custom attribute on containerless custom element, does not get element

Tags: element, aurelia, custom-attributes, custom-element

I was developing a custom attribute named `OnScreenKeyboardCustomAttribute` in aurelia. After jobs went done, I was trying to use it an custom element which includes an input and I want this element to work on that input. By default I get the element inside the attribute class and expect it to be input or text field.

But while on that custom attribute, the input element is inside some other elements. So I think the next step is to move into element and achieve the inner input. This is possible but when the custom attribute has containerless annotation, I receive no element inside the attribute class and instead I receive `<!--anchor-->`. So how can I achieve to the inner element?

custom element - viewmodel

```
import {
  containerless,
} from 'aurelia-framework';

@containerless()
export class CInputCustomAttribute {
}
```

custom element - view

```
<template>
  <div class.bind="paClass ? paClass : 'row margin_bottom'">
    <div class.bind="labelClass ? labelClass : 'column_large_3 column_small_4'">
      <label for="${id}" class="label_inline" class.bind="errors.length ? 'text_red' : '' "><span class="required_star"
          if.bind="star">*</span>${label}</label>
    </div>

    <div class.bind="inputClass ? inputClass : 'column_large_9 column_small_8'">
      <input id="${id}" placeholder="${placeholder}" class="input toggle_input" class.bind="errors.length ? 'validate-error' : '' "
        value.bind="value" type="${type}" maxlength="${max ? max : 5000}" click.trigger="typeof runFunction=='function' ? runFunction():''">
      <span class="message_red">
        <template repeat.for="error of errors">
          ${error.error.message}<br>
        </template>
      </span>
    </div>
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

custom attribute - viewmodel

```
@inject(Element, BindingEngine)
export class PaOnScreenKeyboardCustomAttribute {

constructor(element, bindingEngine) {
    this.element = element;
    console.log(this.element);
  }
```

usage

```
<c-input type="text" id="username" pa-on-screen-keyboard max="11">

console: <!--anchor-->
```

Comment: Again, a reminder that signatures will be removed here. Additionally, [religious material](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295810/do-we-allow-religious-invocations-in-questions-answers) will be removed. We get the odd theist here that is _determined_ to proselytise, and it usually is not well received. Please save it for your blog, social media, or for a site dedicated to discussing theism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `containerless`, there *isn't* an element to pass to your custom attribute. That's the nature of using `containerless`. The custom element is removed from the markup at runtime, but your custom attribute has to be attached *somewhere*, so the framework puts it on the "anchor" comment element. And thus, that's what it passes in to your attribute.

My recommendation, and this is **always** my recommendation, is to not use `containerless` unless it is absolutely necessary. Don't use `containerless` b/c it "makes your markup look nicer at runtime" or because "the custom element being there breaks our CSS." I've been building Aurelia applications since before it was publicly announced, and aside from wrapping third party components where I can't modify the CSS, I have yet to have a need use `containerless`. I even have a rule to not use it in my TSLint rules.

And a situation like this is the exact reason I avoid using `containerless`. It causes wonky issues. Custom elements generally should be just that.. elements. And a containerless element isn't really an element.

Comment: "... And a containerless element isn't really an element.". So great answer @Ashley Grant. Thanks.

Comment: I got the same problem because I wanted to use querySelector() on the element. Even if I understand and share your point of view I think somewhere, maybe Element, someone should manage this situation giving back some hook the dev can use. For now and for me, this is kinda a bug.
BTW thanks for the explanation Ashley

Comment: It isn't a bug, it's the expected behavior. By using `containerless`, you tell the framework not to put the custom element itself in your markup at runtime. Then you attempt to call `querySelector` on an element that doesn't exist. You have to pick one or the other. Either use `containerless` to keep the element out of your markup, or don't use it and be able to use `querySelector` on the element. You can't call functions on objects that don't exist.